# Can I use an external monitor with nvidia-prime

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I've had my old laptop for more than 5 years now and it is time to replace it.

When I'm working (typing, reading, running some applications etc) I always use a dual monitor setup with my current laptop. I am quite used to it and would like to keep using dual monitors.
I know that bumblebee doesn't work with a dual monitor setup if the outputs are wired through the nvidia card but I was wondering if dual monitors work with nvidia-prime while running on the intel card (I want to run it on the intel card since it occasionally runs for extended periods of time and I can't really log out and back in again at that time).
If it doesn't work does anyone know of a way to make it work besides activating the nvidia profile with prime-select?

I am planning on buying a laptop with a Nvidia Geforce GTX 950m graphical card

Answer (score 0):

I have used Optimus with multiple screens (laptop + 2 external) with a dockingstation on my ThinkPad T530. It is very tricky to get it all setup and running. In my laptop screen videos are just fine, but in my external screens I saw a bit of screentearing. I tried with a few linux distros. Fedora 23 was the first one.
It pretty much works out-of-the-box with the opensource drivers on two screens, and it was a bit of a hassle to get it working on the third screen too. Only then I found out that the nVidia driver was routed so that the Intel chip wasn't used any more.
Thats not what Optimus is meant for.
Then I tried it with the proprietary nVidia driver. No succes at all.

After that I decided to give Debian 8 a try. This time I figured out that the proprietary driver in combination with the bumblebee project gave me the best results. I could use optirun on all three screens. The Intel chip presented the desktop and I could use optirun to fire up any program that runs better on 'the much faster video chip'. But, it's an illusion to think that this all easy to do. I had to install about three programs. One of those is a special Intel resolution/screen tool that gets the other two screens working besides the laptop screen. Then you have to manualy tweak the Bumblebee settings. (over and over and over) I cannot even reproduce the steps it took to get it working.
Ubuntu 14.04 was the last one I tried it on. It has the Prime profile configuration that comes with the proprietary driver. It is a pitty you have to logout and back in to get the configuration working. So you end up with either the Intel chip on or the nVidia chip on per session. I found it very annoying to close all my applications and relogin if I wanted to use the other chip. So I decided to try the things I did to Debian on Ubuntu (they have a lot in common). With a few tweaks this worked too, but I had the same crappy experience with videos and games on any of my external screens.

I have come to the conclusion that it will work in some cases, depending on your laptops video chips and hardware configuration. Either you go with the logout-login method or you use Bumblebee. If there is another way, I would be delighted to hear it.
So in your case I would recommend to look into the intel-virtual-output tool. This tool can configure your Intel chip to use your external screens while keeping the nVidia chip turned off.

I hope this gets you any further

Comment: I'll look into it. My current laptop has a nvidia optimus card as well and I got the secondary monitor to work without activating my nvidia card but about 1 year ago my setup somehow broke and I wasn't able to activate the nvidia card properly anymore. The secondary monitor kept working however. So with my current setup I reboot my pc into windows when I want to play a game and I go back to linux for everything else